# Registry read only working in ISE

Tags: powershell, registry, powershell-ise

I'm trying to read a value from the registry as part of a PowerShell script.  The rest of the script works just fine, but the read doesn't seem to unless I run it in ISE.

```
# Do some PS-y stuff

$registryKey = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MyRegistryPath'
if (Test-Path $registryKey)
{
    $registryValue = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $registryKey -Name QA).QA
    if ($registryValue -eq 'True') # default is case-insensitive
    {
        # Do some conditional PS-y stuff
    }
}

# Do some more PS-y stuff
```

When I run it in ISE (with or without breakpoints) or from a cmd console, the *conditional PS-y stuff* happens.

But I'm trying to run this as part of a post-build in Visual Studio (2013 Ultimate).  I get the first *PS-y stuff* and *more PS-y stuff*, but not the *conditional PS-y stuff*.

Here's my post-build:

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug (
    powershell -command "set-executionpolicy unrestricted"
    powershell ChocolateyInstall.ps1
)
```

**UPDATE**

It turns out that the environment is different when running in Visual Studio vs running from cmd (or PS).  I'm running Win7 x64, and `$ENV:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` gives `x86` from VS and `AMD64` from the command line.

Comment: Is one of them running elevated and other not?

Comment: No, both are elevated.

Comment: What is the actual value of `$registryValue`?

Comment: In my registry, I've set it to `True`.  I understand that PS is case-insensitive by default.

Comment: Repeating myself: what is the actual value of `$registryValue`. Check the type as well. Also, how exactly are you running the script from CMD?

Comment: Repeating myself: When I run it in ISE (with or without breakpoints), the conditional PS-y stuff happens.  That includes any attempt to output the contents of variables.  I can only know what's in it when I'm in the ISE.

Comment: PowerShell is NOT case sensitive. also why not starting the PS console directly?

Comment: This is intended to go in a Chocolately package, and I'm testing it as part of a post-build step in VS.  I want to be sure it runs from the command line.

Comment: Id try without the call operator for a start. probably even just paste the script in the console first

Comment: Would that change how just that *part* works?  Remember the rest of the script works just fine.

Comment: I don't see any issue

Comment: Try running the script like this: `powershell.exe -File "myscript.ps1"`

Comment: if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug (
        powershell -command { set-executionpolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser -Force; .\ChocolateyInstall.ps1}
    )
 not sure if you need to set executionpolicy but if you do try remote0signed first